# Caching Loopback REST connector

Tags: rest, caching, loopbackjs

Loopback has the concept of [non-database connectors](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Non-database+connectors), including a [REST connector](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/REST+connector).

What is the right way of caching get requests to such data source?

Comment: If anybody has already implemented anything like this, it would be awesome to share it with the community because I wasn't able to find anything about this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting thought... I think you'd have to do this yourself by creating a new [custom remote method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) and check a local hash of values:

```
// in /common/models/myModel.js

var cache = {};

MyModel.lookup = function loopkup(someParam, next) {

  if (cache[someParam]) {
    // first see if the value is already in the cache
    return next(null, cache[someParam]);

  } else {
    // otherwise do the REST remote method call...
    MyModel.restLoopkup(someParam, function lookupCallback(err, data) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    cache[someParam] = data;  // ...and then set the new cache value.
    next(null, data);
  });
};

MyModel.remoteMethod(
  'lookup',
  {
    accepts: { arg: 'param', type: 'object', http: { source: 'query' } },
    returns: { arg: 'results', type: 'object' },
    http: { verb: 'get', path: '/lookup' }
  }
);
```

This code would set up an endpoint at `.../api/MyModels/lookup?param=foobar` for the calling code to hit. Note that you would probably want to also set an expiration time for the data and properly manage the "cache". You could also use something like a redis store for the values instead of in-memory like I've done above.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you think it'd be easy to implement a global cache cleaner after any update/create of a ModelEntity? I mean for the solution you proposed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Easy? Maybe not... but I'd probably implement a redis cache for this anyway. Especially when you start loading up the cache with other data. Eventually that memory load will impact your application and using a redis cache will make this much more scalable and manageable.